# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') on react-quill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-quill, react-quilljs

Who do I receive this error in console when running my program?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'value') on react-quill

Why can't I get the text from the text editor that made using react-quill? But if I'm using a basic input tag text type, it can get the text from the input.

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState('');
  const [suggestionPart, setSuggestionPart] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const userValueRef = useRef();
  userValueRef.current = userValue;

  function handleUserInputChange(e) {
    const newUserValue = e.target.value;

    const diff = newUserValue.substr(userValue.length);

    if (suggestionPart.indexOf(diff) === 0) {
      setSuggestionPart(suggestionPart.substr(diff.length));
    } else {
      setSuggestionPart('');
    }

    setUserValue(newUserValue);
  }

  function findSuggestionFor(phrase) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get('http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name='+phrase)
        .then(result => {
          const found = result.data.find(university => university.name.indexOf(phrase) === 0);
          if (found) {
            resolve(found.name);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        })
    });

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userValue.length > 0) {
      findSuggestionFor(userValue)
        .then(universityName => {
          const stillFits = universityName.indexOf(userValueRef.current) === 0;
          if (stillFits) {
            setSuggestionPart(universityName.substr(userValueRef.current.length));
          } else {
            setSuggestionPart('');
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setSuggestionPart('');
        });
    } else {
      setSuggestionPart('');
    }

  }, [userValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userValueRef.current);
    inputRef.current.selectionStart = userValueRef.current.length;
    inputRef.current.selectionEnd = userValueRef.current.length + suggestionPart.length;
  }, [suggestionPart]);

  return (
    <ReactQuill 
    placeholder="testing..."
    modules={App.modules}
    formats={App.formats}
    ref={inputRef}
    onChange={e => handleUserInputChange(e)}
    value={userValue+suggestionPart} 
    />
  );
}



export default App;
```

Comment: I was getting this exact error over the weekend on my own React project. Tried like the devil to corner it, but failed. It seems harmless. Then, today, I was at a different site, opened the debugger to do some arithmetic, and they were having the same error on the console, 2x/sec. Also a React app. This is with Chrome Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64). So, my guess is it's a Chrome bug. Now, I'm ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you're using isn't a native HTML element and does not emit a native *change* event.

From the [react-quill documentation](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#props)...

> `onChange(content, delta, source, editor)` : Called back with the new contents of the editor after change.

Your change handler should be defined like this

```js
function handleUserInputChange(newUserValue) {
  const diff = newUserValue.substr(userValue.length);

  // etc
}
```

and bind it to the component props like this

```jsx
<ReactQuill 
  placeholder="testing..."
  modules={App.modules}
  formats={App.formats}
  ref={inputRef}
  onChange={handleUserInputChange}
  value={userValue+suggestionPart} 
/>
```